# How to Systematically Add Slots to a Minecraft GUI Container

Tags: user-interface, for-loop, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have created a new Tile Entity using Minecraft Forge.
It is a simple chest with 81 slots (9 rows, 9 columns).
Basically, I need to create an x and a y coordinate.
Every interval of i, add `SLOT_X_SPACING` to the x coord, but reset to 0 after 9 intervals.
Every 9 intervals of i, I need to add 18 to `SLOT_Y_SPACING`.
**How Can I rearrange these `For` loops into just one loop?**
(I felt that my whole container class was necessary because just the for loop wouldn't be enough info)

```
public class ModDrawerContainer extends Container {

    private ModTileEntityDrawer tileEntityInventoryBasic;

    private final int HOTBAR_SLOT_COUNT = 9;
    private final int PLAYER_INVENTORY_ROW_COUNT = 3;
    private final int PLAYER_INVENTORY_COLUMN_COUNT = 9;
    private final int PLAYER_INVENTORY_SLOT_COUNT = PLAYER_INVENTORY_COLUMN_COUNT * PLAYER_INVENTORY_ROW_COUNT;
    private final int VANILLA_SLOT_COUNT = HOTBAR_SLOT_COUNT + PLAYER_INVENTORY_SLOT_COUNT;

    private final int VANILLA_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX = 0;
    private final int TE_INVENTORY_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX = VANILLA_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX + VANILLA_SLOT_COUNT;
    private final int TE_INVENTORY_SLOT_COUNT = 81;



    public ModDrawerContainer(InventoryPlayer invPlayer, ModTileEntityDrawer tileEntityInventoryBasic) {
        this.tileEntityInventoryBasic = tileEntityInventoryBasic;

        final int SLOT_X_SPACING = 18;
        final int SLOT_Y_SPACING = 18;

        final int HOTBAR_XPOS = 12;
        final int HOTBAR_YPOS = 232;

        for (int x = 0; x < HOTBAR_SLOT_COUNT; x++) {
            int slotNumber = x;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(invPlayer, slotNumber, HOTBAR_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * x, HOTBAR_YPOS));
        }

        final int PLAYER_INVENTORY_XPOS = 12;
        final int PLAYER_INVENTORY_YPOS = 174;

        for (int y = 0; y < PLAYER_INVENTORY_ROW_COUNT; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < PLAYER_INVENTORY_COLUMN_COUNT; x++) {
                int slotNumber = HOTBAR_SLOT_COUNT + y * PLAYER_INVENTORY_COLUMN_COUNT + x;
                int xpos = PLAYER_INVENTORY_XPOS + x * SLOT_X_SPACING;
                int ypos = PLAYER_INVENTORY_YPOS + y * SLOT_Y_SPACING;
                addSlotToContainer(new Slot(invPlayer, slotNumber,  xpos, ypos));
            }
        }

        if (TE_INVENTORY_SLOT_COUNT != tileEntityInventoryBasic.getSizeInventory()) {
            System.err.println("Mismatched slot count in ContainerBasic(" + TE_INVENTORY_SLOT_COUNT
                                                  + ") and TileInventory (" + tileEntityInventoryBasic.getSizeInventory()+")");
        }

        final int TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS = 12;
        int TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * i, TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
        TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8 + 18 *1;
        for (int i = 9; i < 18; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i-9), TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
        TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8 + 18 *2;
        for (int i = 18; i < 27; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i-18), TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
        TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8 + 18 *3;
        for (int i = 27; i < 36; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i-27), TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
        TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8 + 18 *4;
        for (int i = 36; i < 45; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i-36), TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
        TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8 + 18 *5;
        for (int i = 45; i < 54; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i-45), TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
        TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8 + 18 *6;
        for (int i = 54; i < 63; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i-54), TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
        TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8 + 18 *7;
        for (int i =63; i < 72; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i-63), TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
        TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8 + 18 *8;
        for (int i = 73; i < 81; i++) {
            int slotNumber = i;
            addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber, TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i-72), TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canInteractWith(EntityPlayer player)
    {
        return tileEntityInventoryBasic.isUseableByPlayer(player);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack transferStackInSlot(EntityPlayer player, int sourceSlotIndex)
    {
        Slot sourceSlot = (Slot)inventorySlots.get(sourceSlotIndex);
        if (sourceSlot == null || !sourceSlot.getHasStack()) return null;
        ItemStack sourceStack = sourceSlot.getStack();
        ItemStack copyOfSourceStack = sourceStack.copy();

        if (sourceSlotIndex >= VANILLA_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX && sourceSlotIndex < VANILLA_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX + VANILLA_SLOT_COUNT) {
            if (!mergeItemStack(sourceStack, TE_INVENTORY_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX, TE_INVENTORY_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX + TE_INVENTORY_SLOT_COUNT, false)){
                return null;
            }
        } else if (sourceSlotIndex >= TE_INVENTORY_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX && sourceSlotIndex < TE_INVENTORY_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX + TE_INVENTORY_SLOT_COUNT) {
            if (!mergeItemStack(sourceStack, VANILLA_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX, VANILLA_FIRST_SLOT_INDEX + VANILLA_SLOT_COUNT, false)) {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            System.err.print("Invalid slotIndex:" + sourceSlotIndex);
            return null;
        }
        if (sourceStack.stackSize == 0) {
            sourceSlot.putStack(null);
        } else {
            sourceSlot.onSlotChanged();
        }

        sourceSlot.onPickupFromSlot(player, sourceStack);
        return copyOfSourceStack;
    }

    @Override
    public void onContainerClosed(EntityPlayer playerIn)
    {
        super.onContainerClosed(playerIn);
        this.tileEntityInventoryBasic.closeInventory(playerIn);
    }
}
```

Here is a Picture of the Inventory so that you can visualize whats going on:
[image: DrawerGUI.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the horizontal position, you can use the **modulo operator** (`%`) to get the remainder of dividing by 9, which will do what you want.  `i % 9` will always return a value from 0 to 8.  For that you'd use `TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i % 9)`.

For the vertical position, you can simply use division to get the row - `i / 9` will be the current row.  So to get that position you'd use `8 + 18 * (i / 9)`.

Putting both of those together and using `slotNumber` in the loop rather than `i` produces this:

```java
final int TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS = 12;
final int TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS = 8;

for (int slotNumber = 0; slotNumber < TE_INVENTORY_SLOT_COUNT; slotNumber++) {
    addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntityInventoryBasic, slotNumber,
                TILE_INVENTORY_XPOS + SLOT_X_SPACING * (i % 9),
                TILE_INVENTORY_YPOS + SLOT_Y_SPACING * (i / 9)));
}
```